# Chrome and FF does not support javascript ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, cmd, activexobject

My problem is that browsers such as Chrome and FF does not support javascript `ActiveXObject` class. As far as I know it's supported only by IE.
My Chrome console gives an error like `ActiveXObject not found`
Please any help or suggestion. Maybe I can replace it by something else.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where's your code?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - code is pretty simple var r = new ActiveXObject("WSCRIPT.Shell").Run("my cmd commnad")

Comment: Yeah. I don't think there is an equivalent. Although I'd like to be wrong.